# A new UEFI boot record is created on each reboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. Bizzarely, on each reboot, a new UEFI boot record for Ubuntu gets created.

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0029
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0028,0029,0000,0012
Boot0000  Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,afb0f7a3-8d09-4ccf-ad3b-553841c2f4dd,0x96800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....G...............
Boot0012  UEFI: (NTFS) Seagate BUP Slim RD  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(1,0)/HD(4,MBR,0x4294967235,0xa2800800,0x46608000)..BO
Boot0028* ubuntu    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(3,65535,0)/HD(2,GPT,afb0f7a3-8d09-4ccf-ad3b-553841c2f4dd,0x96800,0x82000)..BO
Boot0029* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,afb0f7a3-8d09-4ccf-ad3b-553841c2f4dd,0x96800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)..BO
```

Above, the Boot0028 record is the one that used to point to `GRUBX64.EFI`. On reboot, it points to `PciRoot/...`, and a new record (Boot0029 in this case) gets created. (The output of the command above contained dozens of records like 0028, but I manually removed all the record between 0012 and 0027 before posting here).

The boot order doesn't change so my machine attemps to boot from 0028, fails, goes to the UEFI BIOS screen, and then I have to reboot again for it to boot.

What's going on and how can it be fixed?

```
$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2
$ uname -r
4.4.0-38-generic
```

My motherboard is Asus Maximus VII Impact with the latest BIOS Version from https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS_VII_IMPACT/HelpDesk_Download:
American Megatrends Inc. 3003, 28/10/2015.

Comment: Not partitinons are going to be created, this are only EFI-boot-entries which are created. Strange behavior. Likely a problem with UEFI-BIOS. Any chance to update UEFI-BIOS to the latest version? What is your hardware?

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the terminology and added motherboard and BIOS details.

Comment: I found a nice thread in [fedoraforums](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=293421) about the topic. It's a bit older, but you should read that, probably it helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know for certain what caused the issue, but after I updated to the Windows 10 Anniversary Update this no longer happens.